# Mean grouped by two columns with window by 3 months and NaN for less than 3 months

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I have to apply the mean calculation in this dataset by customer, account but this mean needs to be applied to each 3 months in these groups. For the customer A1200 that don't has 3 months, the result need to be `NaN`.

```
customer    account    month        invoice
C1000       A1100      2019-10-01   34000
                       2019-11-01   55000
                       2019-12-01   80000
            A1200      2019-10-01   90000
                       2019-11-01   55000
            A1300      2019-10-01   10000
                       2019-11-01   10000
                       2019-12-01   20000
C2000       A2100      2019-10-01   78000
                       2019-11-01   55000
                       2019-12-01   80000
```

I tried to use this command, but the average looks incorrect.

```
df_3m.groupby(['customer','account']).mean()
```

Are there some ideias in `pandas` or `pyspark`?

Comment: Just to confirm if the grouping doesn't have full three months then do not do anything with the corresponding amount. Just replace the amount with `nan`? What happend if there are 4 months, calculate the mean of first 3 months and replace the 4th month's amount with `nan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df = df.groupby(by=['customer', 'account']).mean()[df.groupby(by=['customer', 'account']).count() > 2].reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  customer account       invoice
0    C1000   A1100  56333.333333
1    C1000   A1200           NaN
2    C1000   A1300  13333.333333
3    C2000   A2100  71000.000000
```

Comment: Hey, nice! It works perfectly!
I didn't know this trick `[df_3m.groupby(by=['customer', 'account']).count() > 2]`, what's this? And how it combines with another part of code?

Comment: Thats the condition, its like this: `df[df['number'] < 100]` where you are only selecting the rows in `df` where the column `number` has values less than 100

Answer (score 3):

Data

```
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| customer | account |  month   |  invoice |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| C1000    | A1100   | 01-10-19 |    34000 |
| C1000    | A1100   | 01-11-19 |    55000 |
| C1000    | A1100   | 01-12-19 |    80000 |
| C1000    | A1200   | 01-10-19 |    90000 |
| C1000    | A1200   | 01-11-19 |    55000 |
| C1000    | A1300   | 01-10-19 |    10000 |
| C1000    | A1300   | 01-11-19 |    10000 |
| C1000    | A1300   | 01-12-19 |    20000 |
| C2000    | A2100   | 01-10-19 |    78000 |
| C2000    | A2100   | 01-11-19 |    55000 |
| C2000    | A2100   | 01-12-19 |    80000 |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Your Query

```
res = df_3m.groupby(['customer','account']).mean()
```

Query to filter accounts with `less than 3 months`

```
lt_3 = df.groupby(['account']).count() >2
```

Final Result

```
res[lt_3]
```

Output

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| customer | account |   invoice    |
+----------+---------+--------------+
| C1000    | A1100   | 56333.333333 |
|          | A1200   | NaN          |
|          | A1300   | 13333.333333 |
| C2000    | A2100   | 71000.000000 |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```